# How do I reserve an IP address and mac address of computer on windows server 2008/2012 core version?

Tags: ip, cmd.exe, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I have users on the AD running DHCP,and I added them on the WiFi group of the AD, once you authenticate on the group, you will assigned an IP via DHCP.

Now I want to reseve that IP to the machine mac address using the Netsh command.

Comment: Is your server running the DHCP server? (most likely: yes, but please explicitly mention that)

Comment: Thansk bro, I just edited the question description

Comment: Nore sure how to do this in core yet. With the GUI on 2008 it was like this: 
On the server go to [start] [Administrative Tools] [DHCP].

Note that [netsh has hdcp commands](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490941.aspx)
In the left pane go to [IPv4]. "DHCP scope name". There should be an option called "reservations".
Right click that, select "new reservations", fill in the desired host name, desired IP address and the MAC-adress

Note that [netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490941.aspx) has DHCP options.

Comment: Thanks Hennes for the help but I need the command line version. I have more experience with linux, but my new job I am forced to work with windows server core, and on the core version everything is done on  cmd , which I don't really know commands for DHCP reversation

Comment: What happens when you try the following at a command prompt? `netsh`, `dhcp` . If you do not have a range for reserver MAC addresses yet: `add iprange 172.16.1.1 172.16.254`.  The next command would probably be `add reservedip ReservedIP MACAddress [ClientName] [ClientComment] [{DHCP | BOOTP | BOTH}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reserving IPs in DHCP server on Windows Server 2012 R2

10.10.10.0 is the network IP adress.
10.10.10.1 is the ip leased by the DHCP server to the client.
8ca98287993a is the mac address of the client.

1. netsh DHCP server scope 10.10.10.0 show clients
   2 .netsh DHCP server scope 10.10.10.0 add reservedip 10.10.10.1  8ca98287993a**

That is how to reserve an ip on windows server 2008 r2 and 2012 core on command line.